# Android Javamail libraries not being seen?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I'm following this example:

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a/2033124#2033124)

But it isn't working, its breaking when it going into the GMailSender class But I believe I have determined what the problem is for some reason android ins't able to see the Javamail libraries.

I'm not sure why that is I have added the libraries through my project via "Build Paths -> Add External Archives". Am I suppose to add them somewhere else or in a different way in order for  my android to "see" the javamail Libraries??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your jar files are checked in Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export.